# Automatically select categories on new post based on GET value

Tags: categories

Im looking for a solution in admin panel when admin click on a specific link to add new post automatically select one or more categories based on GET value.

for example if admin click on fallowing link  **wp-admin/post-new.php?cat=news**
in the add new post page automatically check the **news**  category in category selection section.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you start to edit a new post, already a post with the status `auto-draft` is created. Actually, what you see is this post. So you can hook into the transition filter `new_to_auto-draft` and add a category to this post:

```
add_action( 'new_to_auto-draft', function(  $post ) {
    // Bail out, if not in admin editor.
    if ( ! strpos( $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], 'wp-admin/post-new.php' ) ) {
        return;
    }

    // Bail out, it no category set in $_GET.
    if ( empty( $_GET['cat'] ) ) {
        return;
    }

    $cat = wp_unslash( $_GET['cat'] );

    // Bail out, if category does not exist.
    if ( false === ( $cat = get_category_by_slug( $cat ) ) ) {
        return;
    }

    wp_set_post_categories( $post->ID, array( $cat->term_id ) );

} );
```

## Explanation

As I've said, a post is created in the moment, you open the editor. [`wp_insert_post()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_insert_post/) is calling `wp_transition_post_status( $new_status, $old_status, $post )` where the $new_status is `auto-draft` and the old "status" is `new`. [`wp_transition_post_status()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_transition_post_status/) basically fires three action hooks:

- [`transition_post_status`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/transition_post_status/)
- [`{$old_status}_to_{$new_status}`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/old_status_to_new_status/)
- [`{$new_status}_{$post->post_type}`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/new_status_post-post_type/)

I am using `{$old_status}_to_{$new_status}` (`new_to_auto-draft`) because it is the most precise for what you are trying to accomplish.

In the function, where we get the post object as parameter (`$post`), we bail out if we are not in the correct location or the `$_GET['cat']` is not found. With [`wp_unslash()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_unslash/) we remove '\' and stuff from `$_GET['cat']`. Another possibility would be to use [`sanitize_key()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/sanitize_key/), maybe it is even more appropriate.

We now load the category object with [`get_category_by_slug()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_category_by_slug/) since we will need the ID of the category to attach the post to the category in [`wp_set_post_categories()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_set_post_categories/). If the category was not found `get_category_by_slug()` will return `false` and we bail out. Another idea would be to create a category with this slug, if the category was not found.

## For Custom Post Types and Custom Taxonomies

In response to

> This does not seem to work on a custom post type/taxonomy

The above example works explicitly on the post type `post` and the taxonomy `category`. If you want to use it with a custom post type and a custom taxononmy, you will need to use [`get_term_by()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_term_by) instead of `get_category_by_slug()` and you will need to use `wp_set_object_terms()` instead of [`wp_set_post_categories()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_set_object_terms).

The example below registers a post type, a taxonomy and shows the process:

```
add_action( 'new_to_auto-draft', function(  $post ) {
    // Bail out, if not in admin editor.
    if ( ! strpos( $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], 'wp-admin/post-new.php' ) ) {
        return;
    }

    // Bail out, it no category set in $_GET.
    if ( empty( $_GET['post_type'] ) || 'post_slug' !== wp_unslash( $_GET['post_type'] ) ) {
        return;
    }

    // Bail out, it no category set in $_GET.
    if ( empty( $_GET['cat'] ) ) {
        return;
    }

    $cat = wp_unslash( $_GET['cat'] );

    // Bail out, if category does not exist.
    if ( false === ( $cat = get_term_by( 'slug', $cat, 'tax' ) ) ) {
        return;
    }

    wp_set_object_terms( $post->ID, array( $cat->term_id ), 'tax' );

} );
add_action ( 'init', function() {
    $args['label'] = 'Test';
    $args['public'] = TRUE;
    register_post_type( 'post_slug', $args );

    $args['label'] = 'Taxonomy';
    register_taxonomy( 'tax', 'post_slug', $args );
});
```

Comment: This does not seem to work on a custom post type/taxonomy (despite replacing wp_set_post_categories with wp_set_object_terms)...any ideas?

Comment: Hi @Stephen, I expanded the answer above.